# c++ static_cast returns zero

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Here is my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int n = static_cast<int>(50 * (60 / 99));

    printf("Floor: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the function print 0 when it should print 30?

Because the result of calculation is : 30.30303030

Comment: its more like 0.6 .. how can make the hole calculation to return 30?

Comment: 60/99 is evaluated as integer math, so the result is 0. Change either value to floating point: ` 60.0f / 99.f` will do is one way to do the job.

Comment: One way to archive this is using another language such as JavaScript, or a language you develop that supports `static_cast`, division that always return floating-point value, and all of other features you want.

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research effort. The answer to this question is trivial to find, both on SO and in other resources.

Comment: too bad i could not show you my search history... i did search it for like 2 hours...

Comment: You may do `(50 * 60) / 99` to stick with integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of calculation is not `30.30303030` but `0` because

1. `60 / 99` is calculated. The result is truncated toward zero because this is integer division and the result is 0
2. `50 * 0` is calculated. The result is 0.

You should do the calculation using `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

    int n = static_cast<int>(50.0 * (60.0 / 99.0));

    printf("Floor: %d\n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Using `50 * (60.0 / 99)` or `50 * (60 / 99.0)` instead of `50.0 * (60.0 / 99.0)` is also OK because other operands will be converted to `double` to match types, but using `50.0 * (60 / 99)` isn't good because `60 / 99` is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much :D I didn't think double will help :D problem solved. Now I can code the rest of the system easy. Since 50 is a variable PlayerLevel.